# How to add a third party DLL to a CSharp Project using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

**How** to add a third party DLL using Roslyn to a CSharp Project?

I am not getting any code where we can add third party DLL-s ..

Comment: Do you want to add a DLL reference to a project in Visual Studio using a VS extension?

Comment: Yes creating a plugin for Visual Studio, using upcoming Roslyn Compiler as a Service..

Comment: I've implemented a VS extension which can add DLL references, you can have a look at the source code here: http://nugetreferenceswitcher.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: I think roslyn is only used to manipulate code, if you want to manipulate projects and solutions you need to use the VS objects...

Comment: Done it easily , through Roslyn we can manipulate Visual Studio Projects and Solutions too.

Comment: Can you provide a link where this is explained? Roslyn is just a compiler, i dont think you can manipulate VS projecs and solutions...

Comment: @RicoSuter - explore Nuget package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis which includes classes like "Solution" and "Project"

Comment: Nice... was fighting with the solution and project COM objects for my VS extension http://nugetreferenceswitcher.codeplex.com, maybe these days are over in vs14

Comment: @RicoSuter if u found this question relevant then u can upvote it, as someone downvoted it by thinking no such solution exists..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved it using following code

```
 NameSyntax name = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("your namespace");
 UsingDirectiveSyntax obj = SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(name);
 var newusing = newDocRoot.Usings.Add(obj);
 root = root.WithUsings(newusing);
```